# Searching a string in java

Tags: java, string

I am a bit lost here, i have been searching this for sometime.

I have a string `$#897950%-1`. Now i need to see if it contains a `-1` in it. I tried

`str.contains("-1")` but it did not work. Can someone guide me to solve this ?

Comment: You can use regex, if you know how to use it.

Comment: What is the issue? How exactly does it not work?

Comment: @smit. Regex for this task???

Comment: `System.out.println("$#897950%-1".contains("-1"));` prints true. Either you do something else, or if you got your string from a file for example, it might look like it contains `-1` but actually contains different characters...

Comment: @RohitJain Why not? Its trivial task though. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Probably you can paste your complete code here, difficult to figure out otherwise

Comment: @smit.. Regex is suitable if we want to match some substring that is not fixed, but follows some pattern. Now in this case, since we know we only want to match `-1`, then of course Regex is not the correct way to go.

Comment: @smit I mean, you could dig a hole in the ground for a plant using a Caterpillar excavator, but is it worth it?

Comment: @RohitJain and jsn I got what you want to say. But OP saying `str.contains("-1")` this is not working so it could be a alternative.

Comment: It works fine for me. Better you post your code so we can work on real issue.

Comment: There are probably non-printing characters in your string, between the '-' and '1'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried it out as:

```
public static void main(String ar[]){
    String str="$#897950%-1";
    System.out.println(str.contains("-1"));
}
```

And See, what eclipse saw me, (It just work fine and gave me `true` as output):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Check whether you really have this string. May be debugger or output system replaces something.

I have the following code printing 'true'

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String str = "$#897950%-1";
    System.out.println(str.contains("-1"));
}
```